# Rewrite на Nuxt3 / Nitro / H3

Tags: javascript, node.js, 1с, nuxt.js

Стандартная ссылка обмена с сайтом 1с такая.

```
http://<сайт>/<путь> /1c_exchange.php? type=catalog& mode=init
```

Подставив путь можно переписать так:

```
https://example.com/api/1c/exchange?type=catalog&mode=init
```

Я хочу чтоб она обрабатывалась файлом

```
~/server/api/1c/exchange/[type]/init.js
```

Как можно реализовать реврайт url без внешнего web сервера?